# I am trying to prove how is $i^2 = -1$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

As the title mentions I am trying to prove that $i^2 = -1$ but am not sure about how to do so correctly. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Very sorry for the confusion, my teacher had asked to show that $i^2=1$ but I quickly realized this was wrong and corrected the question. i in this case is defined in polar form as $i = 1(cos(pi/2))+i(sin(pi/2))$

Comment: It's a bit difficult, since actually $i^2=-1$.

Comment: And how do you define $i$?

Comment: Since you tagged this with complex-numbers tag, Im going to assume you mean $i^2=-1$.  This is definition. No proof required.

Comment: @Tyler.Mett That is how it is defined. You're just denoting the square root of -$1$ with $i$ which is actually imaginary.

Comment: $i$ is by definition the solution of $x^2+1=0$, so it can't be proved since it's a definition...

Comment: I find the comments saying "the definition of $i$ is $i^2 = -1$" or something like that rather confusing. First of all, this is not a definition since the corresponding equation has two solutions in $\mathbb C$. Secondly, there is not just a *single* definition of $i$. We need to know what the OP's definition of $i$ is (which may have to do with the definition of $\mathbb C$).

Comment: Please state your definitions of $\mathbb C$ and $i$.

Comment: very sorry for the confusion, my teacher had asked to show that  $i^2=1$ but I quickly realized this was wrong and corrected the question. i in this case is defined in polar form as i = 1(cos(pi/2))+i(sin(pi/2))

Comment: "in this case is defined in polar form as i = 1(cos(pi/2))+i(sin(pi/2)) "  What does the $i$ on the right-hand side mean, then?

Comment: @Tyler.Mett so, given the values of $\cos$ and $\sin$ at $\pi/2$, your definition of $i$ is... $i=i$?

Comment: in class we use the form a+bi for complex numbers and use the complex plane to find the polar form. i think I need to use the polar form as definition to prove that $i^2 = -1$

Comment: But the whole thing is -- how do you formally define a complex number then? You cannot just say "a complex number is a number of the form $a+ib$" without defining $i$, or at least stating some of its properties. Otherwise, that "definition" of complex number is not a definition at all.

Comment: then $ i = sqrt(-1)$ is all we know for this problem. but my answer has to include the polar form and not just say that the square of some square root is the number inside it.

Comment: I suspect your intended exercise was (a) convert $i$ to polar form and (b) use that polar form to square $i$.  So do you know the polar form of $i$?  Do you know how to multiply numbers in polar form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think  complex number as ordered pair and isomorphic to R ^2 and form a field over `R. Defined by the additive operation as (a,b)+(c,d)= (,a+c,b+d) and multiplicative operation as (a,b)*(c,d)= (ac-bd, ad+bc) now i ^2= (0,1)*(0,1)=(-1,0) =-1.

`